# Permalink / sub-template issue

Tags: permalinks, templates, search, page-template, links

I've got a WP page with many subpages with their own template. The main template includes them. Each element with its own template can be received with an id and an anchor that is linked to this idea, like so:

**CHILD TEMPLATE**

```
<li class="customer" id="<?= ( basename(get_permalink()) );?>">
<a href="#<?= ( basename(get_permalink()) );?>">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="<?= field('logo') ?>" />
    </div> <!-- END .logo -->
</a>
```

Each child template has its own URL, of course.

Now my problem is: when I use the built-in WP search, I get the permalink to this child template, when the matched keyword is on one of the child template pages. This causes an display error, because just the child template gets loaded and not the whole site it is placed at.

Can u help me to get the right link that leads me to the child template anchor on my site it is placed in?

That's my **SEARCH**

```
<div class="container search">

  <h1>
     Suchresultate für 
  <? 
     /* Search Count */ 
     $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
     $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); 
     $count = $allsearch->post_count; _e(''); 
     _e('<span class="search-term">'); 
     echo $key; _e('</span>'); _e(' — '); 
     echo $count . ' '; _e('Artikel'); 

     wp_reset_query(); 
  ?>
  </h1>

  <? if (have_posts()) : ?>


     <? while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="entry">
           <a href="<? the_permalink() ?>">
              <? the_title() ?>
           </a>
          <? the_excerpt() ?>
        </div>
     <? endwhile; ?>

     <p align="center"><? next_posts_link('&laquo; &Auml;ltere Eintr&auml;ge') ?> | <? previous_posts_link('Neuere Eintr&auml;ge &raquo;') ?></p>

  <? else : ?>
     <h2>Leider nichts gefunden</h2>
     <div class="search-bar">
      <? get_search_form() ?>
     </div>
```

**Thank you very much in advance. Your help is very appreciated! :)**

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what you've done, and it sounds a bit messy, but I think you've created "Pages" using the child templates as the "Template" under page attributes.

[image]

That, or you are linking to them directly with `wp-content/theme/themename/templatename.php`. You never want to link directly like that, but if that were the case I have no idea how the search would "get the permalink".

I don't know how else those templates would "its own URL" and either way would be wrong.

You should be creating all of the pages-- parent and child-- using the "main template" as the "Template". If that template is [constructed correctly](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), everything should load in context correctly.

You should also look into [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part).